# jQuery script has conflict with other script on web page

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, wordpress, conflict

My custom code conflicts with some other JavaScript file in my WordPress website.

Code which ocurs conflict is here. When I remove google APIs for jQuery everything works fine except this code then it stops working. I have tried to modify code with noconflict but it did not help. Maybe I did it wrong.

[Website](https://delivery.beaboutburger.sk)

When script is there it makes address delivery checker stop working.

```
<script>$.noConflict();</script><script 
src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="pondelok" class="msg">
<h4>Objednávky dnes prijímame od 11:00 do 21:00.</h4>
</div>
<div id="utorok" class="msg">
<h4>Objednávky dnes prijímame od 11:00 do 21:00.</h4>
</div>
<div id="streda" class="msg">
<h4>Objednávky dnes prijímame od 11:00 do 21:00.</h4>
</div>
<div id="stvrtok" class="msg">
<h4>Objednávky dnes prijímame od 11:00 do 21:00.</h4>
</div>
<div id="piatok" class="msg">
<h4>Objednávky dnes prijímame od 11:00 do 21:00.</h4>
</div>
<div id="sobota" class="msg">
<h4>Objednávky dnes prijímame od 11:00 do 21:00.</h4>
</div>
<div id="nedela" class="msg">
<h4>Objednávky dnes prijímame od 11:00 do 20:00.</h4>
</div>

<script>
var Now = new Date();
var CurrentDay = Now.getDay();
var CurrentHrs = Now.getHours();
if (CurrentDay == 1 && (CurrentHrs >= 00 && CurrentHrs <= 24)) {
$('.msg').hide()
$('#pondelok').show();
}else if (CurrentDay == 2 && (CurrentHrs >= 00 && CurrentHrs <= 24)) {
$('.msg').hide()
$('#utorok').show();
} else if (CurrentDay == 3 && (CurrentHrs >= 00 && CurrentHrs <= 24)) {
$('.msg').hide()
$('#streda').show();
} else if (CurrentDay == 4 && (CurrentHrs >= 00 && CurrentHrs <= 24)) {
$('.msg').hide()
$('#stvrtok').show();
} else if (CurrentDay == 5 && (CurrentHrs >= 00 && CurrentHrs <= 24)) {
$('.msg').hide()
$('#piatok').show();
} else if (CurrentDay == 6 && (CurrentHrs >= 00 && CurrentHrs <= 24)) {
$('.msg').hide()
$('#sobota').show();
} else if (CurrentDay == 0 && (CurrentHrs >= 00 && CurrentHrs <= 24)) {
$('.msg').hide()
$('#nedela').show();
} else{
$('.msg').hide()
$('#no_del').show();  
}

var weekday = new Date();
weekday[0]=  "Nedeľa";
weekday[1] = "Pondelok";
weekday[2] = "Utorok";
weekday[3] = "Streda";
weekday[4] = "Štvrtok";
weekday[5] = "Piatok";
weekday[6] = "Sobota";

var n = weekday[tomorrow.getDay()];
document.getElementById("nextDay").innerHTML = n;

var jq211= jQuery.noConflict();

</script>
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: It looks like you're importing jQuery at least twice, which is never ever a good idea.

Comment: But When I deleted script url from this code it did not work.

Comment: Describe "didn't work." Were there errors in your console?  Keep in mind that when you use `.noConflict()`, it clears jQuery such that you can no longer use `$`.

Comment: @Marc yes there are some errors you could check it here https://delivery.beaboutburger.sk/ ...Im newbie in js so I could not do it very well.

Comment: @Marc on that url there is a adress field where you could check if your adress is in delivery area. Under intro there is orange line with 11 to 21 00 time. If I remove jquery from there it displays all lines as you could see in HTML code. If jquery is there, delivery checker does not work.

Comment: Please revise your post to format (indent) your code properly. You shouldn't work like that and you shouldn't expect us to do so.

Comment: Remove the duplicate jQuery loads. Remove `$.noConflict();`.

Comment: @Marc check it now what happened. I see all the lines when I removed line with script

Comment: I have removed this <script>$.noConflict();</script><script 
src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: @Marc after I remove it it will display all lines from html for the whole week. It stops working. I need to declare script with jquery there. But this google apis url conflicts with some other jquery but I have no idea which one and what url to type there instead of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone have the same problem I have solved this problem by editing code mentioned in steps bellow.

1. I have removed code bellow due to a double call of jquery.

   `<script>$.noConflict();</script><script  src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`
2. I have replaced all `$` symbols with `jQuery`

Now I have 0 console errors and everything works fine.